# I am learning about classes in javascript and am trying to simulate raindrops. I have created 100 new raindrops but only one of them show up

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am working with classes for the first time and wanted to simulate raindrops. However, the following code only draws 1 raindrop instead of 100. This might be because of the clearRect(0,0,400,400) because when I delete that line, the 100 raindrops show up but without the clearRect, it just creates multiple lines. How would I fix this? Thank you in Advance.

My Code:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = a.getContext("2d");

var objects = [];

class rainDrops {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
    this.y = 20;
  }
  show() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 5);
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();
  }
  move() {
    this.y++;
  }
}

createRaindrops();
drawRaindrops();

function createRaindrops() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    objects[i] = new rainDrops();
  }
}

function drawRaindrops() {
  for (var j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
    objects[j].show();
    objects[j].move();
  }
}
window.setInterval(drawRaindrops, 17);
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @MauriceNino yes, that works, thank you.

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @MauriceNino Yep, I just have to wait for 5 more minutes until it allows me to 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the `c.clearRect(0,0,400,400);` into `drawRaindrops()` before or after the loop and it should work.

```html
<body>
    <canvas width="400" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
      var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var c=a.getContext("2d");

      var objects=[];

      class rainDrops{
          constructor(){
              this.x=Math.floor(Math.random()*300)+1;
              this.y=20;
          }
          show(){
              c.fillStyle="blue";
              c.beginPath();
              c.rect(this.x,this.y,5,5);
              c.fill();
              c.closePath();
          }
          move(){
              this.y++;
          }
      }

      function createRaindrops(){
          for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
              objects[i]=new rainDrops();
          }
      }

      function drawRaindrops(){
          c.clearRect(0,0,400,400); // move it here
          
          for(var j=0;j<objects.length;j++){
              objects[j].show();
              objects[j].move();
          }
      }
      
      createRaindrops();
      drawRaindrops();
      window.setInterval(drawRaindrops, 17);
  </script>
</body>
```